# Unexpected result from fibonacci series using Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm just starting to use `Rcpp` so sorry if I'm missing an easy step or something similar... I have tried this from `?sourceCpp`

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(code='
  #include <Rcpp.h>

  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  int fibonacci(const int x) {
    if (x == 0) return(0);
    if (x == 1) return(1);
    return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2);
  }'
)
```

Up to `fibonacci(46)` everything's fine, but then I get:

```
> fibonacci(47)
[1] -1323752223
> fibonacci(48)
[1] 512559680
> fibonacci(49)
[1] -811192543
> fibonacci(50)
[1] -298632863
```

According to this [page](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html) the above should be:

```
47 : 2971215073
48 : 4807526976
49 : 7778742049
50 : 12586269025
```

Do you get the same result?

Comment: +1 for a self-contained reproducible example. Very nice.

Comment: @SimonO101 Thanks for the +1 (always accepted) but to be honest I just copied and pasted from `?sourceCpp`. Even though I could probably have done the fibonacci function by myself I'm less then basic in the C :-(

Comment: Also, you don't need the `#include` which gets added (along with other scaffolding) by `sourceCpp()`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel oh I see, thanks. Like I said, I've literally started yesterday, so for now I was just following the docs (and code from your workshops) exactly as they are, and even doing so some of them don't compile... question coming...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel then perhaps hadley should update [**his guide**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html#using-sourcecpp)... ?

Comment: Maybe you should tell that _him_ rather than me?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel No, I'm asking, hence the `?`

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I confused myself over the _string_ use with `sourceCpp()` which is unusual.  I'd define a Fibonacci function in one long line via `cppFunction()`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel ok, that's more in line with what I thought [from following *his* guide! :-) ]

Comment: For completeness:  `cppFunction('double fib(double x) { if (x<2) return x; else return fib(x-1)+fib(x-2); }')`

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel just a pure curiosity: `Rcpp` is yours, right? But you say " I'd define a Fibonacci ..." like you mean differently, so I guess someone else wrote the R Doc for `Rcpp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are exceeding the [**maximum limit**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) for signed integers (technically this would be a `long int` I guess). Use `double` instead...

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(code='
  #include <Rcpp.h>

  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  double fibonacci(const double x) {
    if (x == 0) return(0);
    if (x == 1) return(1);
    return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2);
  }'
)

fibonacci(47)
#[1] 2971215073
```

Comment: Oh.. ok. I actually replaced `int` with `long` and it gave the same number... But I didn't think about double I thought long was enough... Thanks anyway!

Comment: `int` and `long` are the same size. But even if you used a larger integer type, R's integer type is itself only so big.

Comment: @Peyton ok thanks I thought int was 16 bit and long 32 ... my bad! Thanks guys.

Comment: @Michele, it depends: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc

Comment: Note: R only has `int` and `double` types. If you need extra precision on your integers, you're stuck with `double`, unless you use an addon package (eg [int64](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/int64/vignettes/int64.pdf))